# How to use jquery to move div to top after click event

Tags: jquery

What I have in the js area is what I have as of now, it's not really doing anything.

```js
$(".blocks .block").on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().hide().prependTo(".blocks").slideDown()
});
```

I'm attempting to use the DOM to add an event where when one block is clicked, it is moved to the top of the other blocks. I've tried .prependTo() and .position(). Nothing I do seems to work, could anyone help?

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  /*justify-content: center;*/
}

.blocks {
  margin-top: 5%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.block--red {
  background-color: red;
}

.block--blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.block--green {
  background-color: green;
}

.block--pink {
  background-color: pink;
}

.block--gray {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
    <div class="blocks">
      <div class="block block--red"></div>
      <div class="block block--blue"></div>
      <div class="block block--green"></div>
      <div class="block block--pink"></div>
      <div class="block block--gray"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: see this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6732420/move-div-to-top-after-click

Comment: I have, it's unfortunately a bit confusing for me to piece together. I'm very new to javascript. Thank you for the reference though!

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".block").on('click', function(event){
    $(".blocks").prepend($(this))
 
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  /*justify-content: center;*/
}

.blocks {
  margin-top: 5%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.block--red {
  background-color: red;
}

.block--blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.block--green {
  background-color: green;
}

.block--pink {
  background-color: pink;
}

.block--gray {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="blocks">
      <div class="block block--red"></div>
      <div class="block block--blue"></div>
      <div class="block block--green"></div>
      <div class="block block--pink"></div>
      <div class="block block--gray"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please upvote and select correct answers. you are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

`prependTo` works fine for this!

Your code doesn't work because with `prependTo()`, you should have `child.prependTo(parent)` as oposed to `prepend()`, where you should have `parent.prepend(child)` ([reference](https://api.jquery.com/prependto/)). It seems you are prepending `$(this).parent()` which is `.blocks` to itself.

```js
$(".block").click(function(){
    $(this).prependTo(".blocks");
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  /*justify-content: center;*/
}

.blocks {
  margin-top: 5%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.block--red {
  background-color: red;
}

.block--blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.block--green {
  background-color: green;
}

.block--pink {
  background-color: pink;
}

.block--gray {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="blocks">
      <div class="block block--red"></div>
      <div class="block block--blue"></div>
      <div class="block block--green"></div>
      <div class="block block--pink"></div>
      <div class="block block--gray"></div>
</div>
```